# How to pass value of radio button which is clicked to Spring MVC controller?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC controller in one of my project.

Below is my JSP code in which it will show three radio button. One is `Insert`, second radio button is `Update` and third radio button is `Delete`.

Once I click `Insert` radio button, it shows two text box next to `Insert` radio button, and same thing with other two radio button as well. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EGJk8/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".changeAction").on("click", function(){
            $('.changeable').html('')
            var divId = "#" + $(this).attr("div-id");
            var myInput = '<label for="Node"> Node </label> <input type="text" name="node" size="20" /> <label for="Data"> Data </label> <input type="text" name="data" size="100"/>'
            $(divId).html(myInput);
        })
    })      
</script>

<body>
<form method="post" action="testOperation">
    <!-- I used only one hidden box to store value -->
    <input type="hidden" name="name" id="dynamicName">
    <input class="changeAction" type="radio" name="tt" value="Insert" div-id="insert"/> Insert
    <div id="insert" class="changeable"></div>
    <br/> <input class="changeAction" type="radio" name="tt" value="Update" div-id="update"/> Update
    <div id="update" class="changeable"></div>
    <br/> <input class="changeAction" type="radio" name="tt" value="Delete" div-id="delete"/> Delete
    <div id="delete" class="changeable"></div>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

Below is my method in Controller code -

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "testOperation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, String> testOperation() {
        final Map<String, String> model = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "testOperation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, String> testOperations(@RequestParam String name, 
                                              @RequestParam String node, 
                                              @RequestParam String data) {
        final Map<String, String> model = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(node);
        System.out.println(data);

        return model;
    }
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Suppose I click `Insert` radio button and type `Hello` in the first text and `World` in the second text box, then I will hit the submit button, and after that I am seeing `Hello` value in `node` variable and `World` value in `data` variable which is correct.

But somehow, `name` variable is coming as empty instead of that it should show `insert` value as I have clicked insert radio button.

And same thing should happen to update and delete radio button..

Any thoughts what wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace Your Javascript by this. It worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".changeAction").on("click", function(){
        $('.changeable').html('')
        var divId = $(this).attr("div-id");
        $("#dynamicName").val(divId);
        divId = "#"+divId;
        var myInput = '<label for="Node"> Node </label> <input type="text" name="node" size="20" /> <label for="Data"> Data </label> <input type="text" name="data" size="100"/>'
        $(divId).html(myInput);
    })
})
```

here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EGJk8/5/

Comment: It's not working at all. In fact, if I am clicking insert radio button, now two text box are also not getting generated if I am using your javascript... You can take a look into your jsfiddle example.. No textbox are getting generated in that as well..

Comment: @AKIWEB my mistake. apology. Now check it is working now. I have updated my answer and jsfiddle both

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as,

From ,

```
@RequestParam String name
```

To ,

```
@RequestParam String tt
```

Because you have mentioned the name of the radio button as `tt` . So can't get the value like `Insert , Update , Delete` .